# What is the term used for the slope of a line compared to the derivative of an equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This may seem like a very simple question to seasoned folks out there, but whenever I see a question that states that variable x changes at a rate of some value, I find it hard to decipher it's meaning.

For e.g: 'The volume of the mountain increases at a rate of 10^7 cubic feet per year'. This confuses me greatly, as I do not know whether this is a derivative, or if it's a linear function, whose slope is 10^7.

So, with a normal linear function whose rate of change is the avg rate of change, you also have a derivative where it's the instantaneous rate of change, but I just never know what it means when a question refers to '**the** rate of change', I mean what is that?

Is it just generally accepted that 'the' rate of change is taken to be the average?

Answer (score 0):

Rate of change is of a function $y=f(x)$ is a ratio of change in $y$ vs change in $x$, i.e. $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\equiv\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ if you look at a momentary rate of change you get a derivative 
$$\frac{df}{d x}=\lim_{x_2\to x_1}\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\lim_{x_2\to x_1}\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$

If $f(x)$ is a linear function, then rate of change is just a slope of the line.

'The volume $V$ of the mountain increases at a rate of 10^7 cubic feet per year' means 
$$\frac{V(\text{year N})-V(\text{ year N+1}) }{1\text{(year)}}\approx 10^7 \text{cubic feet }$$
This is not a derivative in a normal sense, and just a rough approximation of the rate of growth obtained,  of course by  averaging of measurements over several years.
However this is probably good enough for a normal use of this quantity.